# Spring cloud gateway with kubernetes discovery on openshift

Tags: kubernetes, routes, openshift, spring-cloud-gateway, autodiscovery

I'm trying to setup Spring cloud gateway on openshift and want to discover the services available within cluster. I'm able to discover the services by adding the @DiscoveryClient and dependencies as below.

Boot dependencies are like:

```
    spring-cloud.version : Greenwich.SR2
    spring-boot-starter-parent:2.1.7.RELEASE
```

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I can see services are being discovered and registered. And routing also happening but there is CN name validation error occurring while routing. I tried setting the use-insecure-trust-manager:true as well but still the same error.

```
2021-12-31 12:30:33.867 TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-8] o.s.c.g.h.p.RoutePredicateFactory        : Pattern "[/customer-service/**]" does not match against value "/userprofile/addUser"
2021-12-31 12:30:33.868 TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-8] o.s.c.g.h.p.RoutePredicateFactory        : Pattern "/userprofile/**" matches against value "/userprofile/addUser"
2021-12-31 12:30:33.868 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-8] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route matched: CompositeDiscoveryClient_userprofile
2021-12-31 12:30:33.868 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-8] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: GET https://my-gatewat.net/userprofile/addUser ] to Route{id='CompositeDiscoveryClient_userprofile', uri=lb://userprofile, order=0, predicate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.ServerWebExchangeUtils$$Lambda$712/0x000000010072a440@1046479, gatewayFilters=[OrderedGatewayFilter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.RewritePathGatewayFilterFactory$$Lambda$713/0x000000010072a840@3c8d9cd1, order=1}]}
2021-12-31 12:30:33.888 TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-8] o.s.c.g.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter   : RouteToRequestUrlFilter start
2021-12-31 12:30:33.888 TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-8] o.s.c.g.filter.LoadBalancerClientFilter  : LoadBalancerClientFilter url before: lb://userprofile/addUser
2021-12-31 12:30:33.889 TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-8] o.s.c.g.filter.LoadBalancerClientFilter  : LoadBalancerClientFilter url chosen: https://10.130.83.26:8443/addUser 
2021-12-31 12:30:33.891 DEBUG 1 --- [ctor-http-nio-7] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x326a2e7b] Created new pooled channel, now 0 active connections and 1 inactive connections
2021-12-31 12:30:33.891 DEBUG 1 --- [ctor-http-nio-7] reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider            : [id: 0x326a2e7b] SSL enabled using engine SSLEngineImpl and SNI /10.130.83.26:8443
2021-12-31 12:30:33.931 ERROR 1 --- [ctor-http-nio-7] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [8768bf6c] 500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/userprofile/addUser"

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 10.130.83.26 found
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      httpclient:
        ssl:
          use-insecure-trust-manager: true
```

Tried adding SNI matchers in SSL Context, to skip hostname check, but still not working:

```
SNIMatcher matcher = new SNIMatcher(0) {
             @Override
             public boolean matches(SNIServerName serverName) {
                   log.info("Server Name validation:{}", serverName);
                   return true;
             }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to resolve this error by using k8s discovery with url-expression as below:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
          url-expression: "'https://'+serviceId+':'+getPort()"
```

Routes will be registered as https://serivcename:port same URL will be used by SSLProvider where it will create SSLHandler with host in SNI Information rather IP-Address which was causing this failure.

Logs for where SSL provider added handler with SSL Engine only and hostname port.

2022-01-04 14:58:15.360 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-4] reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider            : [63cc8609, L:/127.0.0.1:8091 - R:/127.0.0.1:60004] SSL enabled using engine io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkAlpnSslEngine@31e2342b and SNI my-service:8088